# Failing to match number ranges with pattern declared in DEFINE block using PyPi regex package

Tags: python, regex, python-regex

I'm using https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex (via `pip install regex`, but experiencing a failure here:

```py
pattern_string =  r'''
        (?&N)
        ^ \W*? ENTRY              \W* (?P<entries>    (?&Range)    )     (?&N)

        (?(DEFINE)
             (?P<Decimal>
                 [ ]*? \d+ (?:[.,] \d+)? [ ]*?
             )
             (?P<Range>
                 (?&Decimal) - (?&Decimal) | (?&Decimal)
                 #(?&d) (?: - (?&d))?
             )
             (?P<N>
                 [\s\S]*?
             )
        )
    '''

flags = regex.MULTILINE | regex.VERBOSE  #| regex.DOTALL  | regex.V1 #| regex.IGNORECASE | regex.UNICODE

pattern = regex.compile(pattern_string, flags=flags)

bk2 = f'''
ENTRY: 0.0975 - 0.101
'''.strip()
match = pattern.match('ENTRY: 0.0975 - 0.101')
match.groupdict()
```

gives:

```
{'entries': '0.0975', 'Decimal': None, 'Range': None, 'N': None}
```

It misses the second value.

```
> pip show regex
Name: regex
Version: 2022.1.18
Summary: Alternative regular expression module, to replace re.
Home-page: https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex
Author: Matthew Barnett
Author-email: regex@mrabarnett.plus.com
License: Apache Software License
Location: ...
Requires:
Required-by:

> python --version
Python 3.10.0
```

Comment: @IainShelvington I'm using `regex` package not `re`: https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex as I need to use `DEFINE` syntax which Python doesn't support. I'll update the question.

Comment: Then you need to select the PCRE flavour, not PCRE2, that matches your result.

Comment: Alas I find no reference in the regex repo as to whether it is PCRE or PCRE2 compliant. I suspect neither. Everything else works, so I suspect maybe time to file an issue with the maintainer. Thankyou for the suggestion!

Comment: Yes, selecting PCRE in regex101 -- now the result is in alignment with the Python result. The question now becomes: how to fix the regex?

Comment: No need to file any bugs, the problem is with the optional patterns inside the group definitions in the `DEFINE` block, see the answer below. It is certainly a valid and clear *regex* question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the spaces you defined in the `Decimal` group pattern are consumed, and the `DEFINE` patterns are atomic, so although the last `[ ]*?` part is lazy and can match zero times, once it matches, there is no going back. You can check this if you put the `Decimal` pattern into an atomic group and compare two patterns, cf. [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HQuvtj/4) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HQuvtj/5). `(?mx)^\W*?ENTRY\W*(?P<entries>(?>[ ]*? \d+ (?:[.,] \d+)? [ ]*?) - (?>[ ]*? \d+ (?:[.,] \d+)? [ ]*?) | (?>[ ]*? \d+ (?:[.,] \d+)? [ ]*?))` exposes the same behavior as your regex with `DEFINE` block, while `(?mx)^\W*?ENTRY\W*(?P<entries>[ ]*? \d+ (?:[.,] \d+)? [ ]*? - [ ]*? \d+ (?:[.,] \d+)? [ ]*? | [ ]*? \d+ (?:[.,] \d+)? [ ]*?)` finds the match correctly.

The easiest fix is to move the optional space patterns into the `Range` group pattern.

There are other minor enhancements you might want to introduce here:

- As you are only interested in the captured substring, you do not need to use `regex.match` with the `N` group pattern (`[\s\S]*?`), you may use `regex.search` and remove the `N` pattern from the regex
- You do not need to use a group for a `a|a-b` like patterns, you can use a more efficient optional non-capturing group approach, `a(?:-b)?`.

So, the regex can look like

```
^ \W* ENTRY              \W* (?P<entries>    (?&Range)    ) 
(?(DEFINE)
    (?P<Decimal>
        \d+ (?:[.,] \d+)?
    )
    (?P<Range>
        (?&Decimal)(?:\ *-\ *(?&Decimal))*
    )
)
```

​
See the [regex demo](https://tio.run/##dVF/S8MwEP2/n@JAsMncSqeIONzKXKsUaitdp4hTqV3WFdcftBEU/O71ErvNyjxIuNy99@5yV3zyVZ6d1HWSFnnJoWQx@1CKkHNWZi8VL5MshiFAqaqqAo09w/y@A5Yb@A/QMhEmxu0Fy5DIqpGIEePQD7OYUfGgylaEGMS0rmzXokpLQ/BNFiVpuB61M7LC4ggRg0et@yR8arQhe7Rk8T1K2FdThqLgHDo9PL@Cf6WFHWB@QUUD0APp/9/AjyfGpizXYVzhFOVwtZuZE9gOfhy@msid5V96Uwv1NxHTC8aOAztEf5ezr13Ptybj6U5g5toTz7SUzeK2taI8LZI1I@2FdkF2NJQ3ruT17RgZS9GrXOoAdE0/PzvFT@paX@8rmNEEtSCITkMerRDfaGoVC8toRdS9VBUJBdbkRNK0uMzfi0UScUJpXX8D).

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##dVF/S8MwEP2/n@JAsMncSqeIONzKXKsUaitdp4hTqV3WFdcftBEU/O71ErvNyjxIuNy99@5yV3zyVZ6d1HWSFnnJoWQx@1CKkHNWZi8VL5MshiFAqaqqAo09w/y@A5Yb@A/QMhEmxu0Fy5DIqpGIEePQD7OYUfGgylaEGMS0rmzXokpLQ/BNFiVpuB61M7LC4ggRg0et@yR8arQhe7Rk8T1K2FdThqLgHDo9PL@Cf6WFHWB@QUUD0APp/9/AjyfGpizXYVzhFOVwtZuZE9gOfhy@msid5V96Uwv1NxHTC8aOAztEf5ezr13Ptybj6U5g5toTz7SUzeK2taI8LZI1I@2FdkF2NJQ3ruT17RgZS9GrXOoAdE0/PzvFT@paX@8rmNEEtSCITkMerRDfaGoVC8toRdS9VBUJBdbkRNK0uMzfi0UScUJpXX8D):

```py
import regex
pattern_string =  r'''
        ^ \W* ENTRY              \W* (?P<entries>    (?&Range)    )

        (?(DEFINE)
             (?P<Decimal>
                 \d+ (?:[.,] \d+)?
             )
             (?P<Range>
                 (?&Decimal)(?:\ *-\ *(?&Decimal))?
             )
        )
    '''

flags = regex.MULTILINE | regex.VERBOSE
pattern = regex.compile(pattern_string, flags=flags)

bk2 = f'''
ENTRY: 0.0975 - 0.101
'''.strip()

match = pattern.search('ENTRY: 0.0975 - 0.101')

print(match.groupdict())
```

Output:

```
{'entries': '0.0975 - 0.101', 'Decimal': None, 'Range': None}
```